# how to transfer text from android app to notepad in pc through usb serial port communication?

Tags: android, usb

How to transfer data from android mobile app to notepad in pc through serial port communication?.I have got some code.It establishes connection but I could not able to transfer data to notepad.Please help me with this.

Comment: "I have got some code" - In that case, include it in the question so we can help :)

Comment: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://felhr85.net/2015/01/09/a-dirty-and-quick-example-of-serial-port-communication-in-android/&grqid=WBXnw4iK&hl=en-IN

Comment: Samiles Here is the link for the code.